# Add data_frame column while fulfill condition in dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to add a column to a `pandas.DataFrame`. If the string in the `DataFrame` has one or more words as a key in a dict. But it gives me an error, and I don't know what went wrong. Could anyone help?

data_frame:

```
tw_test.head()

    tweet   
0   living the dream. #cameraman #camera #camerac...    
1   justin #trudeau's reasons for thanksgiving. to...   
2   @themadape butt…..butt…..we’re allergic to l... 
3   2 massive explosions at peace march in #turkey...   
4   #mulcair suggests there’s bad blood between hi...
```

dict:

```
party={}
{'#mulcair': 'NDP', '#cdnleft': 'liberal', '#LiberalExpress': 'liberal', '#ThankYouStephenHarper': 'Conservative ', '#pmjt': 'liberal'...}
```

My code:

```
tw_test["party"]=tw_test["tweet"].apply(lambda x: party[x.split(' ')[1].startswith("#")[0]])
```

Comment: Don't you think the error and traceback might be helpful to know?

Comment: So, whatever you think this is doing: `party[x.split(' ')[1].startswith("#")[0]`, I'm pretty sure it will raise a `TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable` since `.startswith` returns either `True` or `False`, and trying to index into `True[0]` or `False[0]` will fail.

Comment: So how to achieve this function? any other more python code that I can use?

Comment: This is still not working:`tweet_list=tw_["tweet"]
tw_test["party"]=map(lambda x: x.split(" ") in party[k] if x.startswith("#"), tweet_list)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your trouble was due to trying to cram too much into a `lambda`.  A function to do the lookup was pretty straight forward:

**Code:**

```
party_tags = {
    '#mulcair': 'NDP',
    '#cdnleft': 'liberal',
    '#LiberalExpress': 'liberal',
    '#ThankYouStephenHarper': 'Conservative ',
    '#pmjt': 'liberal'
}

def party(tweet):
    for tag in [t for t in tweet.split() if t.startswith('#')]:
        if tag in party_tags:
            return party_tags[tag]
```

**Test Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
tw_test = pd.DataFrame([x.strip() for x in u"""
    living the dream. #cameraman #camera #camerac
    justin #trudeau's reasons for thanksgiving. to
    @themadape butt…..butt…..we’re allergic to
    2 massive explosions at peace march in #turkey
    #mulcair suggests there’s bad blood between
""".split('\n')[1:-1]], columns=['tweet'])

tw_test["party"] = tw_test["tweet"].apply(party)
print(tw_test)
```

**Results:**

```
                                            tweet party
0  living the dream. #cameraman #camera #camerac  None
1  justin #trudeau's reasons for thanksgiving. to  None
2      @themadape butt…..butt…..we’re allergic to  None
3  2 massive explosions at peace march in #turkey  None
4     #mulcair suggests there’s bad blood between   NDP
```

Comment: Thanks. But I got this error:`----> 2 tw_test["party"] = tw_test["tweet"].apply(party)    -> 2220             mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)  ----> 4     for tag in [t for t in tweet.split() if t.startswith('#')]:   AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'` Any idea?

Comment: You data is different than mine. Your tweet column has a float in it.

Comment: I figured out. Need to change the type to unicode.`tw_test.head()
tw_test["party"] = tw_test["tweet"].astype('U').apply(party)` Thanks again.